# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JVideoOCR

Tags: java, java-native-interface

public class JVideoOCR extends Observable
{
    public static final int STATUS_DOCUMENT_REMOVED = 1;

```
public native boolean init();

public native boolean terminate();
public native boolean startRead();
public native boolean stopRead();

static { 

    System.loadLibrary("JVideoOCR"); }

IOCRDataHandler dataHandler = null;

public void setOCRDataHandler(IOCRDataHandler handler)
{
    dataHandler = handler;
}

public void MRZDataCallback(MRZData data)
{
    if (dataHandler != null)
        dataHandler.handleOCRData(data);
}


private void returnStatus(int status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
    case STATUS_DOCUMENT_REMOVED:
        setChanged() ;
        notifyObservers(new Integer(2)) ;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

This code is working fine whent plced that java file to default package but if i am shifting this java file to package it's not working.